# How can I make a Swing text area have the focus as soon as it is loaded?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextarea

I've created a simple Swing panel that, when loaded, takes up my application's entire window. It contains two `JTextArea`s and a handful of buttons. I want one of the text areas to have the focus when the panel loads, so that the user can immediately start typing instead of having to click on the text area first. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm intentionally not including code because I think a general, "teach me how to fish" answer will be better in the long term than a solution that just works for me, but I could add some upon request.

Comment: The problem you describe looks weird: most often, when a panel gets displayed, the first field (based on (x,y) position) automatically gets the focus: Maybe a code snippet could help show what you experience ;-)

Comment: @jfp, I was actually wondering about that; I'm surrounding the field with a border and using a `JScrollPane`. I'll add code eventually, but the machine on which the code resides seems to be having early signs of hard drive failure, so you might not want to wait around....

Comment: @jfp, I take it back, I'm not going to add code. Partially because camickr's answer was perfect for me (both in terms of providing working code and explaining why/how it works), and partially because my attempt to generate a standalone complete compilable code sample that illustrates the problem was taking forever.

Comment: Togamus perfect, I also liked camickr's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default focus goes to the first component defined on the window.

If this is not the component you want to have focus then you need to request focus once the window is realized.

The [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) example shows a couple of ways to do this.

Answer (score 4):

See here [the Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) which contains exactlly what you are searching for (I think):

> A component can also be given the
>   focus programmatically, such as when
>   its containing frame or dialog-box is
>   made visible. This code snippet shows
>   how to give a particular component the
>   focus every time the window gains the
>   focus:

```
//Make textField get the focus whenever frame is activated.
frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        textField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the last thing I tried before asking; it didn't work. That is, putting it in didn't seem to add, remove or change any behavior in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call requestFocus method of Jcomponent class,

public void requestFocus()

On the Component that you want to focus.
And pleas make sure that you call this method after setVisible is called for its parent component.

For example:-
You have a Jframe in which you added a JTextArea, so after calling you should call in following order:-

jframe.setVisible(true);
jarea.requestFocus();